# 404 error with @Scope("request")

Tags: java, spring, scope

This is my applicationContext.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd"
default-autowire="no">

<!-- simple cache manager -->

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
     <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" >
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>

<cache:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.toto" scoped-proxy="interfaces"/>

</beans>
```

And my bean :

```
@Named
@Scope(value = "request")
public class MyBeanImpl extends AbstractBean implements MyBean {

   // some stuff

}
```

This code not work, I have a 404 - not found error when I would like visit the url. But if I use @Scope("prototype") it works, but I need the request scope.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there any Exception and/or stacktrace?

Comment: No with my eclipse console I haven't any exception or error, just : INFOS: Server startup in xxx ms..

Comment: What particular URL are you trying to visit? You want to visit a normal Spring bean in a browser?